# Easily tabbing to previous or next field

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm new to the Android UI and I'm looking to see if there's something similar to iPhone's 'next' and 'previous' buttons you see when filling out a form. Currently I have to hit close keyboard then tap on the next field. I tested this in both an app and in the web browser.

Android version 2.1 on HTC Hero.

Answer (score 1):

Some keyboards have a tab button that shows up when you are filling in a form.  For example the Android stock keyboard has this feature (at least in 2.2+).  Additionally you shouldn't have to close the keyboard to click the next field, unless you are zoomed in very close.

Comment: Someone removed my tags which indicated this, I'm on 2.1 (HTC hero) and don't see that feature. Any idea if it can be enabled?

Comment: You should be able to download and install the 2.2 keyboard on 2.1.  I'm sure there are other keyboards that work on 2.1 that have this, as well.

Comment: Try this link for the stock Gingerbread keyboard: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=875202  This should give you contextual options like "Next", "Done" or "Go" when appropriate.